# Minificar CSS para simplificar

Tags: html, css

Intento minificar mi código css para mejorar la carga de mi web.
He probado por css clean y minify css,pero el código que me devuelve siempre se encuentra comentado. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: 1) Utiliza algún editor con revisión de sintaxis. Puedes tener algún comentario sin cerrar correctamente. 2) Si es algo puntual puedes usar una de tantas webs para realizar la operación. 3) Si realizas ediciones de forma habitual, plantéate instalar un automatizador de tareas, Gulp, Grunt son los más usados. También sirve para Javascript, Sass, Less, Html entre otras muchas funcionalidades.

Comment: El problema de esta pregunta es que está abierta a opiniones (qué solución usar, cómo usarla... etc). Si la pregunta fuese 'cómo eliminar comentarios en css minificado' mejoraría mucho, en mi opinión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado a utilizar [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)? Gulp en si es un automatizador de tareas, pero apoyado por los paquetes de minificacion de css y de js puedes rápidamente minificarte todo el contenido. Ademas de ver muchas otras funciones para las que podría ayudarte.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

gulp.task('minifycss', function() {

  archivosCss=gulp.src('ruta/tus/css');

  return  archivosCss    
          .pipe(cssmin())
          .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'));

});

gulp.task('minifyjs', function(){
  gulp.src('ruta/tus/js')
    .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
});

gulp.task('minifyHTML', function(){
  return gulp.src('./*.html')
              .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace:true}))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

gulp.task('all', ['minifycss','minifyjs','minifyHTML']);

gulp.task('default',['all']);
```

En este ejemplo, minificarias, tus css, tus js e incluso tu html, haciéndolo mucho mas liviano.

Si te decantas por esta opción, y tienes alguna duda durante el proceso, no dudes en hacérmelo a saber y te lo completare con la información que haga falta.

Comment: Como aplico Gulp para minificar?

Comment: Lo primero que necesitarías es ir a la página de Gulp y seguir los pasos para instalarlo.